# webbrowser.open('mailto:....') launches mail client in local execution environment but not on production server

Tags: python, flask, python-webbrowser

I am using the following code to launch the e-mail client with pre-defined fields. The e-mail client launches as expected when I test on my local machine, but not on the production server. On the production server I simply get the redirect to '/'. Any suggestions on what could cause the e-mail client to launch? I tested on all browsers I, and did not see any difference in behaviour.

```
@app.route('/errorform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def errorform():
    form = ErrorForm()
    logs = str(open(file, "r").readlines()[int(file_len(file))]).rstrip()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.includeLogs.data == False:
            webbrowser.open('mailto:test@mail.com?subject=Feedback&body=<insert your message here>')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            webbrowser.open('mailto:test@mail.com?subject=Feedback&body=<insert your message here> \n\n Logs: %s' % (logs))
            return redirect('/')
    return render_template('main.html', form=form, show_results=0, page = 'errorform')
```

Comment: I suppose this is one of the cases where writing the question helps identify the answer.... I'm suspecting that when running on the production server the server becomes the context for the 'webbrowser.open' instruction. Now trying to find a way to change this to a local context instead,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you've got an answer to the first question, here comes a suggestion to the second problem: just redirect to the `mailto:` URL:

```
@app.route('/errorform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def errorform():
    form = ErrorForm()
    logs = str(open(file, "r").readlines()[int(file_len(file))]).rstrip()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.includeLogs.data == False:
            return redirect('mailto:test@mail.com?subject=Feedback&body=<insert your message here>')
        else:
            return redirect('mailto:test@mail.com?subject=Feedback&body=<insert your message here> \n\n Logs: %s' % (logs))
    return render_template('main.html', form=form, show_results=0, page = 'errorform')
```

Worked For Me™ here.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion and providing alternative pointers. Interestingly this is where I started from. The reason why I ended up going down the web browser.open path is that I couldn't get the code to execute with the line break characters (\n\n), whereas this worked fine with browser.open.